# Get List of Ethernet Device Names in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash

I am attempting to create a bash script that creates an array of the Ethernet device names on my PC and not wireless card.   I want to have a list of the names so I can later iterate over them.

For example - Assume I have two ethernet NICs - enp2s0 and enp3s0 and a wireless card - wlp4s0

From `lscpi` I would see

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: <truncated>
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: <truncated>
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless
```

Similarly `ip a` shows

```
1: lo: <truncated>
2: enp2s0: <truncated>
3: enp3s0: <truncated>
4: wlp4s0: <truncated>
```

How can I create an array of the names so I can iterate over them?
enp2s0
enp3s0

I have figured out how to find the first NIC using

```
NIC=$(basename $(udevadm info -e | grep "DEVPATH=.*$(lspci | grep -m 1  Ethernet | cut -f 1 -d\ )/net" | cut -f 2 -d\ ))
```

But I cannot figure out how to loop this approach.  Any suggestions how I can do this in bash?

Thanks

Densha

Answer (score 4):

`nmcli` has an output which can be be parsed easily, but you may have to install it first.

Example output of `nmcli device`:

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION       
eno1    ethernet  connected    wired connection 
wlp2s0  wifi      unavailable  --               
lo      loopback  unmanaged    --
```

To extract only the names of ethernet devices use

```
nmcli device | awk '$2=="ethernet" {print $1}'
```

In this example the output will be `eno1`. You can use the command in a loop as usual.
<sub>Here we assume the first column to be free of special symbols like `*[]?` so that we can use the simple and portable (but potentially unsafe) construct `for variable in $(command)`,</sub>

```
for device in $(nmcli device | awk '$2=="ethernet" {print $1}'); do
    # stuff
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in $(ip a | grep enp | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d":" -f1)
do 
  <something with $f>
done
```

For devices that don't start with "enp" the below is an alternative :

```
for f in $(ip a | grep -B1 "ether" | grep -v ether | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d":" -f1)
do 
  <something with $f>
done
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I want to run on systems that have different device names - not all enp*.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks with the suggestions I modified my original to

```
for DEV in $(lspci | grep   Ethernet | cut -f 1 -d\ )
do
  NIC=$(basename $(udevadm info -e | grep "DEVPATH=.*$DEV/net" | cut -f 2 -d\ ))
  echo $NIC
done
```

Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Try `time udevadm info -e | grep "DEVPATH=.*$DEV/net/"` and `time ip l | sed 's/^ *[0-9]\+: \([^ ]\+\):.*/\1/p;d'` to compare!

Comment: But if you prefer near kernel command, U could: `/bin/ls /sys/class/net/`